# Replacing values in an ArrayList of custom objects

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have a custom class Distraction and an ArrayList of Distractions being shown using an ArrayAdapter.
Upon clicking on individual items in the list, a popup menu appears with the options Edit and Remove.
When Edit is pressed an alert dialog appears with two EditTexts that take user input for name and priority.
I then want to compare the user input to the previously stored value and update if different.
However, the code currently changes the name to blank no matter what I input in any of the fields.

[image: Screenshot of pop up menu when clicking list item]

Code:

Distraction class

```
public class Distraction {                                                                                 


//Distraction properties                                                                               
private String distraction_name;                                                                       
private String distraction_priority;                                                                   
private String distraction_occurance;                                                                  

//Constructor of Distraction type                                                                      
public Distraction (String distraction_name, String distraction_priority, String distraction_occurance)

    this.distraction_name = distraction_name;                                                          
    this.distraction_priority = distraction_priority;                                                  
    this.distraction_occurance = distraction_occurance;                                                
}                                                                                                      


//Getter methods                                                                                       

public String getDistraction_name(){return distraction_name;}                                          
public String getDistraction_priority(){return distraction_priority;}                                  
public String getDistraction_occurance(){return distraction_occurance;}                                

public void setDistraction_name(String distraction_name){                                              
    this.distraction_name = distraction_name;                                                          
}                                                                                                      

public void setDistraction_priority(String distraction_priority){                                      
    this.distraction_priority = distraction_priority;                                                  
}                                                                                                      

public void setDistraction_occurance(String distraction_occurance) {                                   
    this.distraction_occurance = distraction_occurance;                                                
}                                                                                                      
}
```

Code from my Activity

```
//Declare an Array List of Distractions
    final ArrayList<Distraction> distractionsArray = new ArrayList<>();

    //Creation of first sample data
    distractionsArray.add(new Distraction("Example: Text from Alice", "3", "1"));

    //Initialise the custom array adapter (nested ArrayAdapter class at the end of this activity)
    final ArrayAdapter<Distraction> adapter = new distractionArrayAdapter(DistractionsActivity.this, 0, distractionsArray );

    //Bind list view with the custom adapter
    distractions_list.setAdapter(adapter);

    //Adapter onclickable function
    distractions_list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

            //Popup menu for distraction (EDIT, REMOVE)
            PopupMenu popup2 = new PopupMenu(DistractionsActivity.this, view);
            popup2.inflate(R.menu.distraction_menu);
            popup2.show();

            popup2.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                    //WHEN USER PRESSES EDIT
                    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.Edit) {

                        LayoutInflater dialog = LayoutInflater.from(DistractionsActivity.this);
                        final View edit_distraction_dialog_view = dialog.inflate(R.layout.edit_distractions, null);

                        //Create and initialise an AlertBuilder to open a pop-up where
                        //the user will be able to give some info about the distraction
                        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DistractionsActivity.this);
                        builder.setTitle("Edit Distraction").setView(edit_distraction_dialog_view);

                        builder.setView(R.layout.edit_distractions);


                        //Set positive OK button for alert dialog
                        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                                        final EditText input_name = (EditText) edit_distraction_dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.edit_distraction_name_edittext);
                                        final EditText input_priority = (EditText) edit_distraction_dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.edit_distraction_priority_edittext);

                                        final String new_name = input_name.getText().toString();
                                        final String new_priority = input_priority.getText().toString();

                                        final String old_name = distractionsArray.get(position).getDistraction_name();
                                        final String old_priority = distractionsArray.get(position).getDistraction_priority();

                                        if (!(new_name.equals(old_name))){
                                            distractionsArray.get(position).setDistraction_name(new_name);
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            Toast.makeText(DistractionsActivity.this, "No input!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                                        }
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    }
                                });

                        //Set negative CANCEL button for the alert dialog
                        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                    //Close alert dialog
                                    dialog.cancel();
                                }
                            });
                        builder.show();
                    }
                    //WHEN USER PRESSES REMOVE
                    if (item.getItemId() == R.id.Remove) {
                        adapter.remove(distractionsArray.get(position));
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

It also doesn't print the Toast in the else statement.

[image: Screenshot of output after pressing OK on the alert dialog]

Can someone explain why my input isn't passing through and how I can fix it?

Comment: This if statement doesn't matter. `new_name.equals(old_name)`... You would set the name to the old name anyway without checking the strings are equal. Also note: `distraction.getName()` reads much better to Java developers than `distraction.getDistraction_name()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, this code itself should work fine assuming the views are loading correctly.

```
final EditText input_name = (EditText) edit_distraction_dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.edit_distraction_name_edittext);
final EditText input_priority = (EditText) edit_distraction_dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.edit_distraction_priority_edittext);

// You can debug and set breakpoints on these, though
final String new_name = input_name.getText().toString();
final String new_priority = input_priority.getText().toString();
```

---

If you get empty strings, then a few possibilities

1) You typed nothing. But, I doubt that

2) The call to `getText().toString()` is not waiting for you to click a button. But you are doing that on the `positive` click action.

3) You loaded a new View over the top of the other Dialog.

Seems like this is the case

```
// An inflater
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(DistractionsActivity.this);
// An inflated View    
final View edit_distraction_dialog_view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.edit_distractions, null);

// A dialog
final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DistractionsActivity.this);
builder
    .setTitle("Edit Distraction")
    .setView(edit_distraction_dialog_view); // You already called setView!

// Don't need to call it again!
// builder.setView(R.layout.edit_distractions);
```

And you can move the `findViewById` outside the `onClick`

```
builder.show(); // Need to call this first

final EditText input_name = (EditText) edit_distraction_dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.edit_distraction_name_edittext);
final EditText input_priority = (EditText) edit_distraction_dialog_view.findViewById(R.id.edit_distraction_priority_edittext);

//Set positive OK button for alert dialog
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                String new_name = input_name.getText().toString();
                String new_priority = input_priority.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Thank you! I can see now that the second setView call is unnecessary because of "final View edit_distraction_dialog_view = dialog.inflate(R.layout.edit_distractions, null);". 

It works as intended now. Also, thank you for the additional tips - I will implement them.